# Create variables with a suffix of a integer in english words in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, naming

I want to have a for loop or similar that can instantiate variables in the loop, and then be available afterward. I know we often print things in for loops, but I want to actually be able to create variable names that correspond the loop number the for loop is on, and save something to that variable.

For example, suppose I have the below `for` loop:

```
value = 10

for i in range(5):
    value = i + value
    print(value)
```

for which I will get print output:

```
10
11
13
16
20
```

But what if I want to actually create a new variable with each loop, with some prefix of my choosing like `var`, so the first variable could end up being called `var_one` (which would be 10 here), the second `var_two`, etc.?

I want to create:

```
var_one = "Something"
var_two = "Something"
etc... in a loop
```

Make sure to notice how the suffixes are real English words!

Comment: First step - you need to tell people what programming language you are using.

Comment: The usual answer for this is "save the results in an array / vector / dictionary / whatever indexed data structure your language supports".

Comment: David, yes, my bad. Python in my case

Comment: @RaymondChen Yup, since this is Python, a `list` would be a good fit

Comment: You can could use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) along with [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/): `from num2words import num2words;print({f'var_{num2words(i).replace("-", "_")}': i for i in range(1, 11)});`. **Output:** `{'var_one': 1, 'var_two': 2, 'var_three': 3, 'var_four': 4, 'var_five': 5, 'var_six': 6, 'var_seven': 7, 'var_eight': 8, 'var_nine': 9, 'var_ten': 10}`

Comment: vars()[f'var_{value}'] = value